# Blazor server NotFound to use same MainLayout

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following App.razor file:

```
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" >
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>        
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                Sorry, there's nothing at this address.
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I wanted to use same layout for correct and incorrect URL pages.

I want to avoid rerendering and reexecuting the initialization code inside `MainLayout` when navigating from a not found page to a regular page (and the other way around: should only happen if a wrong link is provided in a page).

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Use another layout?

Comment: if I use different layout then also if user again goes back to home page then MainLayout renders again. That is why I wanted to use one layout for Found and NotFound case

Comment: You will need to explain " I wanted to suppress these render and events from MainLayout for both Found and NotFound scenario."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the same layout in both cases but it is not the same instance of the layout that is used.

Move the layout information above `Router` to avoid rerendering of `MainLayout` when going from `Found` to `NotFound` and the other way around.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" >
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" />        
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                <div>
                    Sorry, there's nothing at this address.
                </div>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </LayoutView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```